# version solving failed when try get pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I facing issue that show up to me that message when Trying to get packages

> Running "flutter pub get" in stok_app_a...
>   Because no versions of in_app_purchase match >0.2.2+4 <0.3.0 and in_app_purchase 0.2.2+4 depends on json_annotation ^2.0.0, in_app_purchase ^0.2.2+4 requires json_annotation ^2.0.0.
>
> And because every version of speech_to_text depends on json_annotation
>   ^3.0.0, in_app_purchase ^0.2.2+4 is incompatible with speech_to_text.
>
> So, because stok_app_a depends on both speech_to_text ^0.7.0 and
>   in_app_purchase ^0.2.2+4, version solving failed. pub get failed (1;
>   So, because stok_app_a depends on both speech_to_text ^0.7.0 and
>   in_app_purchase ^0.2.2+4, version solving failed.) exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by assignment dependency_overrides in pubspec.yaml file like that

```
dependency_overrides:
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0
```

to override the json_annotation 2.0.0